# Maximum value to show in cell

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, number-formatting, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

Has anyone a tip on how I can show results of a formula depending on its outcome. 
For example, I want to show the result, but not smaller than -1.

However, I need the real value for further calculations.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. Really, it is difficult to understand your question. Could you edit and add some more info? Just check the replies and you will see the differences between understandings.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value to available to reference, but not displayed, then you can use a Custom Number Format - for example, `[<-1] ;[>=-1]#0;@`

This will display a Space instead of numbers less than -1, and display numbers greater than or equal to -1 as Integers.  However, you will still be able to reference the "correct" value via Cell References.

Comment: Is this also possible in G Sheets?

Comment: @PhilippWohnhaas [Custom Number Formatting, yes](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).  Whether it supports all the conditionals, like Excel does, I do not know - but, that should be *very* simple for you to test, if you are using Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
=IF(your formula here < -1, -1, your formula here)
```

Comment: This is originally what I would propose too, but I don't think it satisfies "However, I need the real value for further calculations."

Answer (score 0):

another way would be to use conditional formatting:

[image: 0]